# How do I change the default mapping for SQLXML?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

Quoting this reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd571237.aspx

> [...]the xml data type can be mapped as a String, byte array, stream, CLOB,
>   BLOB, or SQLXML object. String is the default mapping

How do I change it to SQLXML?

I have tried passing this to the DriverManager.getConnection(), but it changes nothing:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("JDBCBehavior", "0");
props.setProperty("XMLDescribeType", "SQLXML");
```

I also tried putting it into the connection url itself, as ';' separated pairs.

Comment: Have you tried just calling `ResultSet.getSQLXML()`? Also make sure you are using the right JDBC driver (sqljdbc4.jar)

Comment: Mark, yes that works but I want to get the correct columnType from ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType(). It always returns -16, which stands for longnvarchar. I need it to return 2009

Comment: According to this you should not set `XMLDescribeType` to get the behavior: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13753/mssqlserver.htm#i1096241

Comment: I tried that as well, didn't work. It's still -16. I'm also fairly sure that these docs are only for some special kind of WebSphere jdbc driver.

Comment: You might be right, maybe it simply isn't possible; at least none of the Microsoft pages report anything like this.

Comment: Rather frustrating, the msdn page I linked to is really explicitly saying that it is possible. Hence "default mapping".

Comment: Yes, it is rather typical that they don't document how you can change that default mapping.